# Better practice for time zone and currency converting with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My web app is about looking up airplane tickets.

The raw prices is stored in `departure country currency and departure city time` .

I wonder what's the better practice to convert the price in user's preferable currency.

How about create an `currency` field in User model, and convert the price according it.

And I want to show the `updated time` depends on the user's `time zone`.

If the user comes from Japan it will show in Japan time.

If the user comes from Taiwain it will show Taipei time.

Currently I hard code the time in that way,

`flight.updated_at.in_time_zone("Taipei").strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')`

Any suggestion or idea, thanks~

Comment: I would store updated time as UTC+0 and have a separate field for a user' specific timezone in the DB. You can make assumptions about a user' timezone by IP, HTTP headers, etc, and allow them to override it manually in settings.

Comment: Do you know about Internationalizing your app? Esp for dates and currency. Only, from Rails 2.2 up. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

**Currency:**

The [Money gem](https://github.com/Rubymoney/money) can probably help you. It has methods like these:

```
Money.new(1000, "USD").exchange_to("EUR").format # => "€906.86"
```

where `"EUR"` can be the currency stored in your User model.

Exchange rates can be retrieved from several online services with additional plugins (see the gem's README).

**Time zone:**

The [local_time gem](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time) will give you this helper:

```
<%= local_time(flight.updated_at) %>
```

It will render a `time` tag, and update its content with javascript to match each visitor's local time.